# Write a function that prints out every digit of n^100

Tags: java, integer-overflow

I was asked to write a Java function that takes an integer, `n`, and prints out the value `n^100`.

I have no idea how to approach this. I know by conventional means it would overflow as `n` grows. Answers such as: `5.32 x 10^20` are not acceptable. It must be every digit.

So, for example:

```
public void byHundred(int n) {
  result = //some computation that yields the string
  System.out.println(result);
}
```

So, `byHundred(23)` prints out `"14886191506363039393791556586559754231987119653801368686576988209222433278539331352152390143277346804233476592179447310859520222529876001"`

Comment: Have you looked at `BigInteger`?

Comment: Look at the BigInteger class. It uses strings to represent numbers: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: BigDecimal is the way to go...

Comment: @Aeshang, BigDecimal is meant for currency, and not much else.  All of the numbers in this problem are integers, so BigInteger is the right way to go.

Comment: @jameslarge Not much else?  Try implementing any sort of calculator without using `BigDecimal`!

Comment: @DavidWallace HP 16C :-)  But seriously, a scientific-type calculator that's implemented using `double` would be far more accurate than any _physical_ scientific calculator that I've ever owned.  We could talk about implementing a financial-type calculator, but then we're back to manipulating currencty.

Comment: @jameslarge No, a calculator that uses `double` would emphatically NOT be more accurate than anything you've ever owned, unless you've only owned abacuses.  You'd enter `0.1 + 0.2` into a calculator that uses `double`, and it would NOT tell you `0.3`.  The `BigDecimal` class is the only sensible way to implement a usable and accurate calculator.

Comment: @DavidWallace, It would indeed display 3.0 if I told it to display one digit after the decimal point, or it would display 3.0000000000 if I told it to display ten digits.  The most accurate physical, scientific calculator I ever owned could display ten digits, but it stored thirteen.  A double has 16-ish digits of precision---three to six orders of magnitude better depending how you count.  The numbers that you picked, 0.1, 0.2, and 0.3 are special cases that just happen to have exact representations in decimal floating point but not binary floating point.

Comment: @DavidWallace, also BigDecimal, by itself would not solve the problem for a scientific calculator.  A scientific calculator needs floating point, but BigDecimal is fixed point.  That problem could be solved with a wrapper class that would use BigDecimal internally, after computing the correct scale for each new result.  Also, it would need a method to properly round and render results in scientific notation when needed.

Comment: @jameslarge A `BigDecimal` is as precise as you need it to be.  A `double` has limited precision.  I cannot think of a single application where `double` would prove to be more accurate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) and something like,

```
public static void byHundred(int n) {
    BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    String result = bi.pow(100).toString();
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    byHundred(23);
}
```

Output is `14886191506363039393791556586559754231987119653801368686576988209222433278539331352152390143277346804233476592179447310859520222529876001` (as requested).

Comment: There's no need for `String.valueOf(n)` here. You can just use `BigInteger.valueOf(n)`.

Comment: @DavidConrad That is nicer. Edited.

Comment: Ah, well... That simplifies this tremendously.

Comment: You also don't need the call to `toString`, since `println` does that automatically.